Turn off laptop display without putting it to sleep

I tried the suggestions on Turn off display in Windows on command and they aren't suitable.
The Screensaver method only blanks the display without turning it off. Maybe that would work for OLED users.
SendMessage with the params -1,0x0112,0xF170,2 does turn off the display, but it does so by putting the computer into connected standby. This interrupts media which is currently playing, such as YouTube.
I attempted to use DisplayPowerOff, but it doesn't work.
Note: I had about ten minutes where I could indeed turn off the display using either DisplayPowerOff or the powershell SendMessage method, but I think that was a glitch because I can't replicate it.
I tried changing the Console lock display off timeout attribute to 2 in Power Options by enabling it with a registry edit, but it doesn't help me. Prevent Windows 10 from going to sleep on lock screen
I am out of ideas.
Note: Yes, you could set closing the lid to Do Nothing, but then I can't leave my lid open, it's inconvenient for me as I'm sitting on my bed next to my desk man it's within arms reach, and I have to remember to change the Power Plan later. I just want to be able to turn the screen off without putting the laptop to sleep or closing the lid.

How are you calling SendMessage? 0xF170 is literally SC_MONITORPOWER – I had been using it in my own screensaver far back in WinXP before Connected Standby was a thing – so either the call is wrong, or Windows has changed its meaning, and in the latter case if the actual "turn off display" function now invokes something different, then I somewhat doubt there will be a SC_MONITORPOWER_REAL to do what you want :/

As it so happens, i would be using the powershell script to use sendmessage. As a workaround, I learned to lock the computer and change turn display off after setting to 1 minute in Settings app. It's a bit annoying because I just want to call whatever windows is using to turn the display off directly instead of locking and waiting. (Plus i don't actually like the turn off display after 1 minute apart from this one use case)

You can do this using little portable apps such as Don't Sleep, NirCMD

Using Don't Sleep

Open App > Monitor > Monitor Off

Using NirCMD

Goto NirCMD Path, Open CMD here with command nircmd.exe monitor off
